# Strange MySQL replication update error (Magento)

Tags: mysql, magento, replication, mariadb

MySQL replication is a little bit new to me, but it looks like I've got it working up till some errors I don't understand.

Some background: I'm replicating all databases (over SSL) from a MySQL 5.6.22 server to a MariaDB 10.0.15 server, which isn't doing anything else than being a dedicated slave to the master. It executes some queries but then runs into an updating problem with a Magento database. If I skip this query, it will just run into a similar query which causes the same error.

This is the error the slave status gives me:

> Could not execute Update_rows event on table magento_db.log_visitor; Column 'visitor_id' cannot be null, Error_code: 1048; Can't find record in 'log_visitor', Error_code: 1032; Column 'visitor_id' cannot be null, Error_code: 1048; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.000121, end_log_pos 7656

Exec_Master_Log_Pos is 7215, but I assume that's irrelevant and the error is in the next query (/transaction block).

Here is a piece of the (verbose) mysqlbinlog:

```html
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 7215
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7292 CRC32 0xf975481b  Query thread_id=25 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1427674785/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 7292
# at 7358
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7358 CRC32 0x0312921e  Table_map: `magento_db`.`log_url_info` mapped to number 2528
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7497 CRC32 0xe3704a8b  Write_rows: table id 2528 flags: STMT_END_F
### INSERT INTO `magento_db`.`log_url_info`
### SET
###   @1=12534083 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2='http://www.myshop.com/catalog/category/view/id/29?cat=31&color=22&dir=desc&order=position&price=9-' /* VARSTRING(765) meta=765 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @3=NULL /* VARSTRING(765) meta=765 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
# at 7497
# at 7565
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7565 CRC32 0x340012cd  Table_map: `magento_db`.`log_visitor` mapped to number 2513
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7656 CRC32 0xd3d2e26f  Update_rows: table id 2513 flags: STMT_END_F
### UPDATE `magento_db`.`log_visitor`
### WHERE
###   @1=3036630 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
### SET
###   @2='deq65v4ks7tgahp2lvih8s74j1' /* VARSTRING(192) meta=192 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @3=1427667585 /* TIMESTAMP(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @4=1427667585 /* TIMESTAMP(0) meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @5=12534083 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @6=1 /* SHORTINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
# at 7656
# at 7714
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7714 CRC32 0xc1eee09b  Table_map: `magento_db`.`log_url` mapped to number 2529
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7770 CRC32 0xf7bcccad  Write_rows: table id 2529 flags: STMT_END_F
### INSERT INTO `magento_db`.`log_url`
### SET
###   @1=12534083 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2=3036630 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @3=1427667585 /* TIMESTAMP(0) meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
# at 7770
#150330  2:19:45 server id 1  end_log_pos 7801 CRC32 0x51775dd4  Xid = 29537
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 7801
#150330  2:19:53 server id 1  end_log_pos 7886 CRC32 0xd6d724c7  Query thread_id=26 exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1427674793/*!*/;
```

`visitor_id` is the first column that shows in phpMyAdmin, but also when I perform `SHOW COLUMNS FROM log_visitor;`, so I'm guessing this column maps to '@1' (couldn't find how to verify this). But when I search for a record with visitor_id 3036630, it just finds one. Note that this is not due to external queries, when I perform `START SLAVE;` again, it hangs on the same error. Also, I tried running mysql_upgrade on the slave, but other than some warning, this solved nothing.

Bottom line is: I don't know how to interpret this error, am I maybe looking at the wrong query? It feels to me there shouldn't be an error, maybe some incompatibility?

Any suggestions are welcome!

EDIT: As requested, a SHOW CREATE TABLE, which seem the same on both servers after doing a diff, except for the increment index:

```html
CREATE TABLE `log_visitor` (
 `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
 `session_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Session ID',
 `first_visit_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Visit Time',
 `last_visit_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Last Visit Time',
 `last_url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last URL ID',
 `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3036631 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Log Visitors Table'
```

The slave was created by dropping all databases (I've had multiple attempts), doing a mysqldump with all databases after acquiring a read lock on the master, importing it into the slave and then starting the slave at the right position. It does some queries and when I look, it already got to an update error like the one described here.

Comment: Are the table schemas exactly the same in both DB's?  The errors would suggest that an update which works on master is not working on the slave due to differences in column definition.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Updated the question, anonimously as I was logged out apparently

Comment: Could it be that the slave requires an explicit value for @1 too at the "query"? Like "WHERE @1 SET @1 - @6" instead of "WHERE @1 SET @2 - @6", even though @1 will remain the same. Some incompatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I found the solution. I once copied/adjusted a nice my.cnf for the master, which included the MySQL 5.6 setting "binlog_row_image = MINIMAL". This causes the binlog to skip columns in the SET-clause of an UPDATE, that are already in the WHERE-clause and are unchanged. MariaDB does not seem to have implemented this setting and the default binlog ROW format requires a value for all fields.